# Java: how convert this strange url to normal?

Tags: java, url

I have got a url from facebook as this:

```
http:\/\/a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-snc7\/s2048x2048\/582167_359167994154900_1489271360_n.jpg
```

It looks strange and I suppose that is one of well known standart but I don;t find the answer in google.

Could you say how I can get normal url from that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

that's because it is escaped you have to unescape it

```
String url="http:\/\/a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-snc7\/s2048x2048\/582167_359167994154900_1489271360_n.jpg";
url=URLDecoder.decode(url);
```

Comment: 1. This doesn't even compile. 2. If you escape the `\ `s properly, `decode()` does nothing with the url. 3. `decode()` is deprecated.

Comment: Excuse me, but URLDecoder.decode(url) works fine. What do mean when say "If you escape the \ s properly, decode() does nothing with the url"? Could you please extend your answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
String newString = replaceSample.replace("\\/", "/");
```

That is because strings Are escaped

Comment: Your first argument should be "\\/", this doesn't compile.

Comment: Sure. Sorry for misspelling. But as they are other answers my may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

simply what you can do is :

```
replaceSample.replace("\", "" );
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

If you found this string in a `*.html` file, then this is the result of manually making the URL unusable by any standard URL-processing. This is not a proper URL. This not the result of any standard escaping.

On the other hand: If you found this string inside some source code (NOT Java, though), then the `\/` might be replaced *at compile time* into plain `/` as the following example in C shows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char *cp = "http:\/\/a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-snc7\/s2048x2048\/582167_359167994154900_1489271360_n.jpg";

    printf("%s\n", cp);
}
```

The output is:

```
http://a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s2048x2048/582167_359167994154900_1489271360_n.jpg
```

In **Java** the compiler will complain about "invalid escape sequence" and not even compile.